# Ios WKWebView intercepting http/https requests

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

My android version of the app using WebView and relies on `shouldInterceptRequest` method to provide svg resources that are being downloaded at the runtime and requested by `http/https` from WebView.
It is desirable to migrate such behavior on ios version of the app. However it seems that `WKWebView` does not provide tools for intercepting `http/https` requests. Given that it is mandatory to use `WKWebView`, what strategies can be employed to achieve similar behavior on ios?

Comment: I am also stuck with this problem, but instead of GCDWebServer, I am using the Telegraph server. Is there any way I can set the origin manually or intercept requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've ended up using. [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer)

I've setup local webserver like so:

```
let webServer: GCDWebServer = GCDWebServer()

webServer.addGETHandler(forBasePath: "/", directoryPath: baseResourcePath, indexFilename: "index.html", cacheAge: 0, allowRangeRequests: true)
```

Then to provide files that are located outside of index.html contained directory
one has to attach custom get handler:

```
webServer.addHandler(forMethod: "GET", pathRegex: "images", request: GCDWebServerRequest.self) { request in
        let fileName = request.path.components(separatedBy: "/images/")[1]
        var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .docmentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        documentsURL.appendPathComponent("images/\(fileName)")
        let response = GCDWebServerFileResponse(file: documentsURL.path)
        return response
    }
```